# Platform Independent GigE Vision driver

Tags: c, camera, computer-vision, vision

Is there a platform independent GigE Vision driver or software package that exists?  I am integrating a Point Grey Research Flea3 GigE camera with a Texas Instruments C6678 multi core DSP chip.  I was hoping to find a piece of software that had explicitly broken out any of the hardware dependent calls into a platform or portable file that I could then fill in the specific details for my platform to transmit a UDP packet, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the GigE Vision standard, while claiming to be open, is actually not an open standard at all.  It requires a license fee to implement in any commercial software, and is not even publicly available for download without approval from [AIA](http://www.visiononline.org).

I was able to find one truly open implementation of the standard:

[OpenGigEVision](https://gitorious.org/opengigevision)

Comment: I don't know what universe they get their definition of open from!

Comment: to date, I would not recommend that implementation - it is pretty incomplete - speaking as someone who's reviewed it and decided to implement one himself.  Avaris also is an option to play with but it does not use the reference implementation of GenICam - this means it is also not to be trusted because GenICam is a very complex thing to support on the PC side - in addition to being implemented with gstreamer.

If you write to AIA, they may provide you a copy of the standard - worked for me.